# Why don't UIButtons interact (change state to highlighted) when touched?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I always faced that issue and never been able to get the answer. When I create the UIButton programmatically and add to the UI and then when you touch the button that state on the **UI** not being changed to highlighted/down as the result of interacting with that button.

Another thing, 'sometimes' UIButtons when they are added through the interface builder, they work fine and when you touch them you can see the state in the UI changed to highlighted/down.

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: You should post your code that isn't working, but buttons state is set to highlighted when you touch down on them, not selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your button type is custom you had to set image / color for highlighted state, to differ the state change (From normal to highlighted).

If your button Type is system, you will see the state change effect without changing image / color.

Comment: That was a very useful answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are noticing the difference between UIButton with type Custom vs. System.

I put together this playground to show the difference.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
view.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

let button1 = UIButton(type: .System)
button1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50)
button1.setTitle("One", forState: .Normal)
button1.backgroundColor = .blackColor()
view.addSubview(button1)

let button2 = UIButton()
button2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: 200, height: 50)
button2.setTitle("Two", forState: .Normal)
button2.backgroundColor = .grayColor()
view.addSubview(button2)

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view
```

Please post your programatic button code, so we can investigate more